# Play audio on image hover in HTML (multiple images)

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first attempt at audio in HTML. So I have a grid of images that have an overlay of text on them, and I want the audio to play a different sound on hover over each image. I got the audio to play but it seems to play the SAME audio file on all images. Can someone help me understand why?

Thank you!

```
  <section class="full_width four_col_grid">
        
  
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="div2">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="image" src="  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" >
      <div class="overlay">När det farliga avfallet och allt som kan materialåtervinnas sorterats ut finns det ofta en rest kvar - soppåsen. 
        Men den kan också återvinnas!</div>
      <audio id="audio">
      <source src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/audio/beep.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
      </audio>
  </div>
    
  <script>
    var audio = $("#audio")[0];
      $("#div2").mouseenter(function() {
      audio.play();
      audio.loop = true;
      });
      $("#div2").mouseleave(function() {
      audio.pause();
      });
  </script>

  
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="div2">
    <div class="container">
      <img class="image" src="  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" >
      <div class="overlay">När det farliga avfallet och allt som kan materialåtervinnas sorterats ut finns det ofta en rest kvar - soppåsen. 
        Men den kan också återvinnas!</div>
      <audio id="audio">
     <source src="http://www.ringelkater.de/Sounds/2geraeusche_gegenst/papier_knuellen.wav" type="audio/x-wav">
      </audio>
  </div>
    
  <script>
    var audio = $("#audio")[0];
      $("#div2").mouseenter(function() {
      audio.play();
      audio.loop = true;
      });
      $("#div2").mouseleave(function() {
      audio.pause();
      });
  </script>

</section>


</main>
```

Comment: Each audio element must have a unique ID otherwise there is a conflict and it may not work as you expect. See related question: [Does ID have to be unique in the whole page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454645/does-id-have-to-be-unique-in-the-whole-page)

Comment: @Yogi thanks for the replyl! Yes I did try changing the audio IDs for each but it's still fixated on ONE audio file! :/

Answer (score 1):

**Steps:**

1. **please remove all script that you have added and add my given script**
2. **replace id attribute of audio tag and place class attribute**

   ```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".image").mouseenter(function() {                
        var audio = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("audio")[0];
        audio.play();
        audio.loop = true;                   
      });

      $(".image").mouseleave(function() {
        var audio = this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("audio")[0];
        audio.pause();    
      });
      })
   ```